# Proof by Induction: Inductive Step Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider $(\mathbb{Z},·)$ where $a·b=a+b-1$ for all $a,b \in\mathbb{Z}$. You may accept as true that $(\mathbb{Z},·)$ is a group with identity $1$ and in the inverse of $d$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is $d^{-1}=2-d$ for each $d \in \mathbb{Z}$. First prove that for any $c \in \mathbb{Z}$, $c^{n}= nc-(n-1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $P_n$: $c^{n}= nc-(n-1)$ for all $n \ge 0$.

We prove $P_n$ is true for all $n \ge 0$.

(1) Show $P_0$ is true.

This part was simple.

$c^{0}= 0·c - (0-1) = 1$

(2) Suppose $P_k$ is true for some $k \ge0$.

$c^{k} = kc – (k-1)$

Show that: $c^{k+1} = (k+1)c – ((k+1)-1)$

So far I have:
\begin{align}
c^{k+1} &= c^k \cdot  c^1 \\
&= (kc – (k-1)) \cdot  c \\
&= c(kc) – ck + c \\
&= c(ck-k) + c
\end{align}

Not exactly sure what to do next, or if I even started this problem the right way.

Comment: Could you please add the whole problem? Would make it a lot easier. As it stands right now, we are looking at something that not even you are sure about.

Comment: What is your 'base case'? Also, I don't see t his holding for any c, since $2c-1=c^2$ would need to hold gir me to be able to do the proof. So far your proof is good (with some detail/explanation of what ylu are doing missing). However for $c=1$ the pronlem is trivial.

Comment: Show Po is true. $^{0}$= 0·c - (0-1) = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base case is correct. For the induction step you need to apply the definition:
$$
c^{k+1}=c^k\cdot c=c^k+c-1
$$
Now the induction hypothesis applies
$$
=kc-(k-1)+c-1=(k+1)c-k=(k+1)c-((k+1)-1)
$$

This proves $c^n=nc-(n-1)$ for all $n\ge0$. Next you need to do it for $n<0$, using that
$$
c^n=(c^{-1})^{-n}
$$
and $c^{-1}=2-c$.

Comment: For $c^{k+1}=c^k\cdot c=c^k+c-1$, where does -1 come from?

Comment: @pancho From the definition: $a\cdot b=a+b-1$.

Comment: WOW! It was there the whole time.....

Comment: @pancho They want to test your ability in not being deceived by habits and to look carefully at definitions. The hours spent on this taught you quite a lot. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the relation $P(k)$ as
$$
c^k = k(c-1) + 1
$$

then
$$
c^{k+1} = c^k \cdot c =_{\text{def}} c^k + c - 1 = k(c-1) + 1 + c - 1 
= (k+1)(c-1) +1
$$

which is the rewritten form of $P(k+1)$